Okta access token type is not JWT
I am using okta application with OIDC and authorization code flow with PKCE. The access token I get from okta is having the following header
{
  "kid": "XYZKID",
  "typ": "application/okta-internal-at+jwt",
  "alg": "RS256"
}

The expected value of typ was JWT.  Would anyone know why I get this typ "application/okta-internal-at+jwt" ?

https://devforum.okta.com/t/okta-access-token-type-is-not-jwt/29515

https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/auth-servers/#org-authorization-server

The issuer for access tokens from an org authorization server is https://{yourOktaOrg}, which indicates that only Okta can consume or validate it. The access token can't be used or validated by your own apps. The contents of the access token are subject to change at any time without notice. Therefore, any attempts to validate the access token may not work in the future.

So, the org's authorization server returns Okta internal tokens?, In my requirement I have SSO login with Okta and I have configured Multi-tenancy in my Springboot OAuth2 resource server. On successful auth, I need my APIs to work with the Okta token. If the type of the token is JWT ( for the Okta dev account ) it works as expected. But if the token is of type "application/okta-internal-at+jwt", the OAuth2 Jose library will fail to validate. What's the solution for this?

you have to use opaque tokens. I

I used Custom Authorisation Server from Okta from which I got tokens of type JWT.

with type JWT token, this should not happen as JWT is meant to be decoded and validated for claims like iss and aud.
